# Does canvas.bind work in a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings, tkinter-canvas

I have a program in Python 3.4.4 using Tkinter, that is supposed to move a square around the screen.

Unfortunately, `canvas.bind` doesn't seem to be working while inside a while loop, but it needs to be inside of the while loop or else the square won't move. This is because I'm technically drawing a new square with different x, y, x1, and y1 coordinates each time the loop runs, and the bind is what makes the square move in each direction according to the arrow keys.

So here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time, random
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = 1000, height = 1000)
canvas.pack()

def move(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        y-=10
        y1-=10
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        y+=10
        y1+=10
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        x+=10
        x1+=10
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        x+=10
        x1+=10


background = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000, fill = 'orange') #draws background
ranNum=random.random()*960  #Creates a random number
ranNum1=random.random()*960 #Creates a random number
food = canvas.create_rectangle(ranNum, ranNum1, ranNum + 15, ranNum1 + 15, fill='green') #creates food
r1 = None
o = 0
length = 4
x = 500
y = 500
x1 = 515
y1 = 515
while o < length:          
    if canvas.find_overlapping(ranNum, ranNum, ranNum + 15, ranNum1 + 15) == True:
        x+=5
        y+=5
        x1+=5
        y1+=5
        canvas.delete(food)
    r=canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x1, y1, fill = 'blue')
    canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Up>', move )
    canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Down>', move)
    canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', move)
    canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', move)
    time.sleep(.0)
    canvas.delete(r1)
    tk.update()
    r1 = r
```

Comment: Don't need update canvas element or Tk() on every step. Why bind event  to canvas ? Bind to main_Tk(mean window),  listen each key if mouse cursor over on canvas.

Comment: So remove tk.update and instead of canvas.bind use main_tk.bind?

Comment: Yes, maybe you delete canvas or canvas element later !

Comment: main_Tk just  brings up a syntax error saying NameError: name 'main_tk' is not defined

Comment: sorry ! `main_tk` is `tk` and where your `tk.mainloop()` line ?

Comment: I'm really sorry im very new to programming in python, it seems i don't have a tk.mainloop(), im assuming i need one though, right?

Comment: @dsgdfg thats seems to have created more problems when i run it with tk.bind, and the mainloop (i believe tk.bind is the problem) it says Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/Python Code/Move the Square.py", line 8, in move
    y-=10
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
(it is any variable, like x or y or y1 or x1, it just depends on the which arrow key I click)

Comment: can't call any  variable if not declared `global` / `class`

Comment: And don't change  x or y, need canvas itemconfigure for every change things.

Comment: okay that answers the question thank you, unfortunately i am new to stackoverflow, so how do i select your comment as an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

don't change x or y, need canvas itemconfigure for every change things